# c++ passing pointer from constructor to constructor

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on learning C++ and I've created 3 classes: NodeEditor, Node, NodeIO.

Essentially the Editor contains a vector of Nodes, each of the Nodes has a vector of NodeIO instances.

I want each class to be able to reference there "owner".

Basically the NodeIO constructor takes a pointer from the Node its in, the Node takes a pointer to the Editor its in.

```
class NodeEditor {
    NodeEditor() {
        ...push_back(Node(this));
    }
}

class Node {
    NodeEditor* owner;
    Node(NodeEditor* _owner) : owner{ _owner } {
        ...push_back(NodeIO(this));
    }
}

class NodeIO {
    Node* owner;
    NodeIO(Node* _owner) : owner{ _owner } { }
}
```

I then need to use the `_owner` pointers later on.

When I attempt this in my project, at first the `_owner` pointer is pointing to the correct location, but once I need to retrieve it later, the actual object no longer exists at that pointers location.

What are my options to allow this sort of layout to work? And is there a different more recommended pattern to follow in this situation.

Comment: The code (as posted) looks like it should work fine; there must be some other reason why your pointers aren't getting maintained properly.  If your classes have explicit copy-constructors and/or assignment-operators, you'll want to verify that they are copying the `owner` member-variables over to their target-objects.

Comment: You are doing everything right in the code that you posted. The error that creates a dangling pointer is somewhere else. The most likely reason I could think about is passing a pointer to "stack" object. Run valgrind or any other memory profiler to find out what is going on.

Comment: Remember that e.g. if you make a naive copy of a `Node` object, then the `NodeIO` sub-objects that the newly-created `Node` object holds will still have `owner` member-variables pointing at the old `Node` object, which is probably not what you want.  (And remember also that data structures like std::vector will make copies of all the objects they hold when they need to resize their internal array larger)

Comment: Hmm thank's for the info, could it be that when I push the object into the vector via the push_back() operation, it kills the pointer location?

Comment: When you add items to a `std::vector` it will sometimes have to re-allocate it's content to keep it contigous in memory. If that happens pointers and references to those objects will become invalidated. Try using a `std::deque` instead and see it that works for you. A `std::deque` never re-allocates it's content.

Comment: I'll give that a shot thanks.

Comment: Why not use `std::shared_ptr<NodeIO>` instead of a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown any copy constructors. By that, I assume that you are relying on the default copy constructors provided by the compiler. That is the source of your problem.

When you use:

```
    ...push_back(Node(this));
```

in `NodeEditor`, you are storing a copy of `Node(this)`. However, if `Node` and `NodeIO` don't have properly implemented copy constructors, the `NodeIO` objects in the `Node` object in the `std::vector` will point to a `Node` object that is not valid -- the temporary `Node` object.

---

Here's a sample program that shows the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node;

struct NodeIO {
   Node* owner;
   NodeIO(Node* _owner) : owner{ _owner } { }
};

struct NodeEditor;

struct Node {
   NodeEditor* owner;
   Node(NodeEditor* _owner) : owner(_owner)
   {
      std::cout << (void*)this << std::endl;
      nodeIOList.push_back(NodeIO(this));
      nodeIOList.push_back(NodeIO(this));
   }

   std::vector<NodeIO> nodeIOList;
};

struct NodeEditor {
   NodeEditor()
   {
      nodeList.push_back(Node(this));
      nodeList.push_back(Node(this));
   }
   std::vector<Node> nodeList;
};

int main()
{
   NodeEditor editor;
   for ( auto& node : editor.nodeList )
   {
      std::cout << (void*)(&node) << std::endl;
      for (auto& nodeIO : node.nodeIOList )
      {
         std::cout << (void*)(nodeIO.owner) << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
0x7ffe53d34c30
0x7ffe53d34c50
0xae10c0
0x7ffe1af7a2a0
0x7ffe1af7a2a0
0xae10e0
0x7ffe1af7a2c0
0x7ffe1af7a2c0
```

The output clearly shows the values of the pointers to the `Node` objects that were constructed using `Node(this)` and the values of the pointers to the `Node` objects that are stores in the `std::vector<Node>`. Please note that the `NodeIO` objects still point to the temporary `Node` objects. They are dangling pointers in `main`.

---

I tried a quick fix but that did not work. I need to work on that a little bit more.

---

Here's a solution that works with default copy constructors. It uses `std::vector` of `std::shared_ptr`s instead of `std::vector` of objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Node;

struct NodeIO {
   Node* owner;
   NodeIO(Node* _owner) : owner{ _owner } { }
};

struct NodeEditor;

struct Node {
   NodeEditor* owner;
   Node(NodeEditor* _owner) : owner(_owner)
   {
      std::cout << (void*)this << std::endl;
      nodeIOList.push_back(std::make_shared<NodeIO>(this));
      nodeIOList.push_back(std::make_shared<NodeIO>(this));
   }

   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<NodeIO>> nodeIOList;
};

struct NodeEditor {
   NodeEditor()
   {
      nodeList.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>(this));
      nodeList.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>(this));
   }
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodeList;
};

int main()
{
   NodeEditor editor;
   for ( auto& node : editor.nodeList )
   {
      std::cout << (void*)(node.get()) << std::endl;
      for (auto& nodeIO : node->nodeIOList )
      {
         std::cout << (void*)(nodeIO.get()->owner) << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
0x1460c30
0x1461110
0x1460c30
0x1460c30
0x1460c30
0x1461110
0x1461110
0x1461110
```

Comment: what would the internals of the copy constructor have to look like to make the pointers point to the proper non-temp locations?

Answer (score 1):

When you add things to a vector, it is possible that *all* the elements of the vector move. Thus, when you add a `Node`, it is possible that all the existing `NodeIO`s' owner pointers are invalidated.

To handle this, you need to either

- Use a different data structure and disable the `Node`s copy and move constructors, or
- During `Node`'s move constructor, update the `owner` pointers of all the `NodeIO`s it contains, and make sure the new `NodeIO`s are constructed correctly if you call the `Node` copy constructor.

Depending on how you store `NodeEditor`s, you should probably do the same with them.

Answer (score 0):

Check life time of NodeEditor object and Node Objects and NodeIo objects.
Use new operator to create dynamic objects, or make sure your instantiation of NodeEditor and Node and NodeIo happens in the same scope.
Check if you keep a copy of Node container of NodeEditor Object and you use it after releasing NodeEditor Object.